# Convert NSString to NSData in Chinese case

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

everybody, I know this question is lots of people to ask and have lots of answer in stack overflow, but In my case, I try to get the JSON format from [here](http://opendata.epa.gov.tw/ws/Data/UV/?format=json), and code like this:

```
// Get JSON


NSString* path  = @"http://opendata.epa.gov.tw/ws/Data/UV/?format=json";
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary* dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];


NSArray* arrayResult =  dic;
NSDictionary* resultDic = [arrayResult objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"resultDic:%@", resultDic);
NSString* uv = [resultDic objectForKey:@"UVI"];
NSLog(@"UVI:%@", uv);
NSString* publicshedTime = [resultDic objectForKey:@"PublishTime"];
NSLog(@"PublishTime:%@", publicshedTime);

NSLog(@"中文");
```

I used :

```
NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But it's not effective to this case, I don't know why.

In console, I can see the Chinese words correctly, and in debugger I can see the "jsonString" content is correct, but I don't know why I convert it to NSData, the content will be wrong, and it output like this :

```
2014-05-27 03:24:09.307 Tab demo[3014:60b] resultDic:{
    County = "\U5609\U7fa9\U5e02";
    PublishAgency = "\U4e2d\U592e\U6c23\U8c61\U5c40";
    PublishTime = "2014-05-27 03:00";
    SiteName = "\U5609\U7fa9";
    TWD97Lat = "23,29,52";
    TWD97Lon = "120,25,28";
    UVI = 0;
}
2014-05-27 03:24:09.308 Tab demo[3014:60b] UVI:0
2014-05-27 03:24:09.308 Tab demo[3014:60b] PublishTime:2014-05-27 03:00
2014-05-27 03:24:09.308 Tab demo[3014:60b] 中文
```

For sure, the other data without Chinese words is display correctly.

This wrong looks like encoding wrong, but I don't know how to fix it correctly, can anyone tell me the way to fix it, Thanks a lot!

Comment: What you're seeing is the Unicode codes for the Chinese characters.  NSLog of an NSArray or NSDictionary will normally "escape" the characters into the `\Uxxxx` form, but if you consult a [Unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/en/#cjk-unified-ideographs) you will see that the correct characters are present.

Comment: Yes, I got it, it cost me 3 hours to learn this experience and knowlege! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't compare contents of objects by their appearance in the console when logged using `NSLog`. That's unreliable because the algorithm to convert objects into strings is not documented, not strict and is for debugging purposes only.

Compare objects by using the `compare:` method.

Comment: Oh my god! I try to display it on my tableview, the Chinese words are display correctly! I'm really love you! thanks a lot!