# JSON-encode UTF-8 string

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, utf-8

How can I get JSON from a URL and encode `NSString` to show using `NSLog`?
The JSON contains Chinese words.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://jxdp.mnks.cn/read.php?xCode=6beff&Code=6beff&Type=1&&top=5&min=0&CALL="]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];

NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
```

Comment: May be this helps you, fi you want to parse and NSLOG JSON Reponse in Chinese. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876602/convert-nsstring-to-nsdata-in-chinese-case#23876716

Comment: In general, you can't rely on NSLog to display extended characters (though it will display valid escapes if the actual characters are not displayed).  This does not in any way affect what would be displayed in a proper text view.